# Is there a previous version of chat.db somewhere?

Tags: messages

When I look at iMessages (chat.db) with SQL they only go back to July 2023. I'm looking for messages from about 6 months ago. Are there any older files kept on the Mac that I'm not seeing in the Messages folder or other folders?

Comment: Is there anything significant in the date itself, July 2023… new Mac, etc? If so, did you migrate from your old one? Do you have iCloud sync on? https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/mm0de0d4528d/icloud Mine goes back to the first message I ever sent from the Mac [based on context], but I can't figure out the date format in english `402833684000000000`

Comment: thanks for the reply. This is the sql i used (found from another website):

Comment: SELECT
    datetime (message.date / 1000000000 + strftime ("%s", "2001-01-01"), "unixepoch", "localtime") AS message_date,
    message.text,
    message.is_from_me,
    chat.chat_identifier
FROM
    chat
    JOIN chat_message_join ON chat. "ROWID" = chat_message_join.chat_id
    JOIN message ON chat_message_join.message_id = message. "ROWID"
ORDER BY
    message_date ASC;

Comment: So honestly im not sure. But it does return everything in imessages back to July 2023. As far as iCloud sync on, yes. I've been using it for as long as i can remember. The Macbook is a few years old and not migrated from any other. I also have iphone messages set to keep "forever" and messages on the Macbook also set to keep "forever". Not sure if this helps but thanks for replying.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421665/how-specificially-do-i-read-a-chat-db-file This gets all messages in chat.db.  Note that the scripts do not extract blob fields which are present in the current version of chat.db.  If messages are really not in chat.db, you would need to look in old backups.

Comment: @Gilby thanks very much! This got me everything dating back to 2015. Any chance you know of an SQL query where i can just see all the data between myself (null) and one other phone number?

Comment: Add this to the WHERE clause: `and (ThreadId = 'xxx')`, replacing the xxx with the phone number you want.

Comment: I should have said: ....replacing the xxx with the phone number or contact name you want.

Comment: Thanks again Gilby! I'm almost there. The result shows that persons responses but not mine. Can i add something that shows only my conversations with them?